# Clarification on how to use Not-in Firestore Operator in Queries

Tags: firebase

The [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not-in) states the following for the `not-in` operator:

> to combine up to 10 not equal `!=` clauses on the same field with a logical `AND`. A `not-in` query returns documents where the given field exists, is not `null`, and does not match any of the comparison values.

I am assuming this `not-in` operator cannot be used on a field on a document that is an array, correct? As in if I had an array field containing `userID's` on a document, I can't use the not-in`` operator to query docs where a particular `userID` is not in that array field.

Comment: It is not possible.